# Windows 10 - Bash (WSL) | How to run Atom build on bash?

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, atom-editor, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I got a lot of problems when I try to run commands on Atom to "bash.exe".

**Step by step**

- Enable "Bash Ubuntu" for Windows 10.
- Setup compiler for my application on "Bash Ubuntu".
- Test from "bash.exe" and "powershell.exe". Everything work ok.
- Install Atom.
- Create an runner on Atom.
- Get msg "Erro: 0x80070057"

**Possible Solutions**

- Disable Legacy Mode on Powershell (github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/7)
- Use Powershell ISE (github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/430)

I've tried both links above, but nothing works.

Here is my Atom error and my Powershell working:

- [Atom IDE with Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Abft.jpg)
- [Powershell with same command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1zfG.jpg)

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Oh, thanks and sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As one of Atom developers said at GitHub issue:

"We support building Atom on Windows using our native Windows environment only. There is no support and no plans to support compiling the Linux version of Atom on Windows using WSL."

You can check at: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13774#issuecomment-278741701